# apex trigger one per Book

Tags: apex, trigger

My problem is easy to understand :

-Contact, Book and Loan are objects

-In Loan (Pret), i have Contact(called Emprunteur here) and Book (called Livre_emprunte)

-Loan is a child of Book and Contact

-Each book cannot be taken by a Contact if an other one as already took it.

So i tried that bellow, and i don't know why.

Any ideas ?

```
Trigger Trigger_1 on Pret__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update) {
if(Trigger.isBefore) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        Set<Livre__c> livreIds = new Set<Livre__c>();
        for (Pret__c pret : Trigger.new) {
            livreIds.add(pret.Livre_emprunte__r);
            Integer result = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Livre__c WHERE id IN: livreIds];
            if(result != 0) {
                pret.addError('Livre déjà emprunté');
            }
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {

    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete) {

    }
}
if(Trigger.isAfter) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {

    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {

    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT : A working solution, thanks to Keith C

```
        // Find the set of books to consider
        Set<Id> bookIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Pret__c loan : Trigger.new) {
            if (loan.Livre_emprunte__c != null) bookIds.add(loan.Livre_emprunte__c);
        }
        if (bookIds.size() > 0) {
            // Find the books already on loan to a Contact
            Set<Id> loanedBookIds = new Set<Id>();
            for (AggregateResult ar : [
                    SELECT Pret__c.Livre_emprunte__c bid
                    FROM Pret__c
                    WHERE Pret__c.Livre_emprunte__c in :bookIds
                    AND Pret__c.Emprunteur__c != null
                    GROUP BY Pret__c.Livre_emprunte__c
                    ]) {
                Id bookId = (Id) ar.get('bid');
                loanedBookIds.add(bookId);
            }
            if (loanedBookIds.size() > 0) {
                // Add the error to the loan being inserted
                for (Pret__c loan : Trigger.new) {
                    if (loanedBookIds.contains(loan.Livre_emprunte__c)) {
                        loan.addError('Livre déjà emprunté');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: I don"t receive any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger code needs to be organised ([bulkified](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)) to avoid queries inside the main trigger loop so the trigger works in the case where bulk updates are done. In this case that can be accomplished by this code (for the straightforward insert case):

```
trigger LoanTrigger on Loan__c (before insert) {
    // Find the set of books to consider
    Set<Id> bookIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Loan__c loan : Trigger.new) {
        if (loan.Book__c != null) bookIds.add(loan.Book__c);
    }
    if (bookIds.size() > 0) {
        // Find the books already on loan to a Contact
        Set<Id> loanedBookIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : [
                select Book__c bid
                from Loan__c
                where Book__c in :bookIds
                and Contact__c != null
                group by Book__c
                ]) {
            Id bookId = (Id) ar.get('bid');
            loanedBookIds.add(bookId);
        }
        if (loanedBookIds.size() > 0) {
            // Add the error to the loan being inserted
            for (Loan__c loan : Trigger.new) {
                if (loanedBookIds.contains(loan.Book__c)) {
                    loan.addError('Book already borrowed');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This is copying an elegant pattern that sfdcfox used in a recent answer that I can't find right now; using the aggregate query lets the database do the work and leaves the code only looping over the Id values that need to have the error set.)

On the subject of always having separate classes, here is [my 2c worth](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/10/30/trigger-handler-induced-design-damage/).

**PS**

My best guess translation back into your terms of the object names:

- Loan__c is Pret__c
- Book__c is Livre__c

and the field names:

- Loan__c.Book__c is Pret__c.Livre_emprunte__c
- Loan__c.Contact__c is Pret__c.Emprunteur__c

Comment: Interesting answer, but it doesn't work. I've edited my trigger like you post it.
Maybe it's a mistake from myselkf, but Book__c and Contact__c are the objects, the related fields are named "Livre_emprunte__c" and "Emprunteur__c". Loan is a child of Book__c and Contact__c

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavyLAURENT I've added the name mappings. I can't see anything wrong with the logic looking at it but that doesn't mean it is right.

Comment: True ^^ I'll try yours with your improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at this again... If you need the code to run on insert only I would do the following;

Firstly keep your triggers and classes separate, it makes things easier to manage.

Trigger:

```
Trigger Trigger_1 on Pret__c (before insert){
    if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert) {
            VerifierLivre.VerifierLivre(Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class VerifierLivre {
    public void VerifierLivre(List<Pret__c> newList){
        for(Pret__c pret : newList){
            Integer result = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Livre__c WHERE id =: pret.Livre_Emprunte__r.Id];
            if(result > 0) {
                pret.addError('Livre déjà emprunté');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should use list of Id's instead of a set of sObjects, you don't need to build a set of the Livre__c sObjects as you are only using the field for that one record.